# What maps MongoDb into memory

Tags: mongodb

Does MongoDb `mmap` everything (i.e. all data files + all indexes) into memory on start?

If database has 100GB and machine has only 4GB RAM, MongoDb mmaps whole database into memory, is it right?

Comment: it maps files into virtual memory. not physical memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB uses memory-mapped files for all data. See the following documentation for how this works:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#what-are-memory-mapped-files

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Checking+Server+Memory+Usage

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo#StartingandStoppingMongo-MemoryUsage

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Caching

Comment: If database has 100GB and machine has only 4GB RAM, MongoDb still mmaps whole database into memory?

Comment: You should preferably aim to have enough RAM for your active working set. This is usually less than your total database size. You can find the size of your indexes and dataSize by doing a `db.stats()` from the mongo console. If your data set is larger than your available memory, then MongoDB is still pretty smart about prioritizing your commonly-accessed data into RAM.

Comment: If your working set is significantly larger than memory, and MongoDB is constantly going to disk for reads (and not just the normal spikes when syncing writes to disk), then you really should be sharding to spread the data across multiple machines/instances.